# What does this crontab line do?

Tags: cron, syntax

What does this crontab entry do?  I'm thinking it means run the jobs.sh script every Monday at 11AM.  Is this correct?

`0 11 * * MON /home/username/jobs.sh`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, thats precisely what it does - the [reference template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) here is really useful in this

```
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |   .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |   |   .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |   |   |   .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |   |   |   |  .----- day of week (0 - 7) (Sunday=0 or 7)  OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |   |   |   |  |
# 0   11  *   *  MON  command to be executed
```

For a more complete understanding, also look at the various special characters and the shorthand forms such as @reboot